# How to fix ReferenceError: Blob is not defined issue when using heic2any library in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, heic

I am facing a problem where I have implemented everything and its working fine actually,
but the main problem is that whenever I try to reload the page it will give me a error saying:
`ReferenceError: Blob is not defined`
I am using `heic2any` library in `nextJs`
I am doing that whenever the user selects a `heic` file `onChange` event, it will convert the `heic` file to png.
everything is working properly but if I reload the page gets crash giving the error `ReferenceError: Blob is not defined`
here is the function where I am using `heic2any` library.
If I comment it out, it will work fine, but then I can't convert `heic` file to any.

```
const onFilesChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      const { files: assets } = event.target;
      if (!assets?.length) {
        return;
      }
       
      
      const validFiles = Array.from(assets).filter(
        ({ size }) => size < MAX_FILE_SIZE + 1
      );
      console.log("FILE SIZE of the file uplaoded::", validFiles.length);
  
      if (validFiles.length < assets.length) {
        // TODO: show error
        alert("File size exceeds,file size should not be more than 10MB");
        setFiles([]);
        return;
      }
      //Todo: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .heic, .pdf, .doc, .docx
      const fileFormat = Array.from(assets).filter(
        ({type}) => type === "image/jpg" || type === "image/png" || type === "image/jpeg" || type      === "application/pdf" || type === "image/heic" || type === "application/msword" || type ===    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
      )
      let heic = assets[0];
      if(heic.name.endsWith('.heic')){
      let randomName = Math.floor(Math.random() * 184) + 1;
      heic2any({
        blob: heic,
        toType: "image/png",
        quality: 0.7,
      }).then((blob) => {
        // let newFile = new File(blob,`heic-${randomName}.jpg`,{type:'image/jpeg'})
        let heicFile = new File([blob], `heicImage-${randomName}.png`, {
          type: "image/png",
        });
        setFiles([heicFile])
      });
        }
     
      if(fileFormat.length < assets.length){
        alert("Invalid file format,only jpg,png,jpeg,heic,pdf,doc & docx file format required");
        setFiles([]);
        return;
      }
  
      setFiles([...files, ...validFiles]);
    };
```

I tried multiple things but non of them worked, therefore I am looking for a solution here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: To fix the error, use a dynamic import to load the heic2any module on the client-side (code sample present at the bottom of this answer)

I was struggling with the same issue today but I was able to fix it with some ChatGPT assistance! I sent the error message to ChatGPT and it explained the following:

> The `ReferenceError: Blob is not defined` error typically occurs when
> the `Blob` object is not recognized by the JavaScript runtime
> environment. This can happen in environments where the `Blob` object
> is not natively supported, such as in Node.js or certain versions of
> Internet Explorer.

I thought "well that's weird, I'm doing front-end development, why is it talking about Node.js?" I don't have deep NextJS knowledge, but in searching about this I learned that NextJS runs both server and client, and some files will run on one or the other. I asked ChatGPT "why is my nextjs code being run server-side?" and it replied:

> In Next.js, the code in your pages directory is run on both the server
> and the client. This is because Next.js uses server-side rendering
> (SSR) by default, which means that the initial page rendering is done
> on the server and then sent to the client as HTML.

The problem happens when you import the heic2any package, so I asked ChatGPT "can I make it so that an import only happens on the client side?" and it replied:

> Yes, you can use dynamic imports to load a module only on the
> client-side. Dynamic imports are a feature of ES6 that allow you to
> load a module at runtime instead of at compile time.

It also provided a code example. The first example didn't work out of the box, but with a little more questioning, I arrived at the solution. This is what worked for me (using Typescript):

```
import { useState } from 'react';

async function convertHeicToPng(imageToConvert: File) {
  // This module will only be loaded on the client side
  const heic2any = (await import("heic2any")).default;

  const convertedBlob = await heic2any({
    blob: imageToConvert,
    toType: "image/png",
    quality: 0.7,
  });

  const fileExt = path.extname(imageToConvert.name);
  const fileNameNoExt = path.basename(imageToConvert.name, fileExt);

  const convertedFile = new File(
    [convertedBlob as Blob],
    `${fileNameNoExt}.png`,
    {
      type: "image/png",
    }
  );

  return convertedFile;
}

function MyComponent() {
   ...
   const handleImageUpload = async (
      e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
   ): Promise<void> => {

    const filesToUpload = e.target.files as FileList;

    for (let i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
      let file = filesToUpload[i];
      if (file.type === "image/heic") {
        file = await convertHeicToPng(file);
      }
      // UPLOAD IMAGE
    }
  };
```

Comment: `const heic2any = (await import("heic2any")).default;` is the key. Thanks.